# Unity rigidbody always falling when on another rigidbody. (Unity 2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm relatively new to Unity, I have a player character and a box sprite, I want the box to be movable by the player and for it to fall, so I gave the box a box collider 2D and a rigidbody2D, the box moves fine and the player can move it OK, however whenever the player is touching the box in any way (standing on it or pushing it) the characters Y velocity begins fluctuating uncontrollably making it play the falling animation. Through some testing I found the problem was the player's rigidbody and boxes rigidbody interaction, I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be great thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think u just need to set both the player character and box sprite 's rigidbody2D to dynamic with 1 gravity scale... u can change their mass to manipulate the motion...